# Get items of the list from dictionary

Tags: python

I try to call up a list stored in the dictionary:

```
obj = {
    'a' : [0,1,2],
    'b' : {
        'c' : [0,1,2]
    }
}
```

The code below is correct for `JavaScript`, but not in `Python`

```
print(obj.a[0], obj.b.c[0])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 57, in <module>
  print(obj.a[0], obj.b.c[0])
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'a'
```

So, How to get the items of the list?

Comment: Have you looked for [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in the Python tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't use `object` as a variable name.

Then, the correct syntax for dictionary access is

```
print(obj['a'][0], obj['b']['c'][0])
```

if you want the first item of the list. If you want the entire list, use

```
print(obj['a'], obj['b']['c'])
```

Answer (score 2):

The Python equivalent is:

```
print (obj['a'][0], obj['b']['c'][0])
```

I've taken the liberty to rename `object` to `obj` since [`object`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#object) is a built-in class name in Python and you don't want to be shadowing that.